# Why am I getting unauthorized in response?

Tags: mailgun

I'm adding a new contact to my contact list and I've followed this example:

```python
from mailjet_rest import Client
import os

api_key = os.environ['MJ_APIKEY_PUBLIC']
api_secret = os.environ['MJ_APIKEY_PRIVATE']
mailjet = Client(auth=(api_key, api_secret), version='v3')
data = {
  'IsUnsubscribed': "false",
  'ContactID': f"{contact_id}",
  'ContactAlt': f"{email}",
  'ListID': "87301",
  'ListAlt': "Leads"
}
result = mailjet.listrecipient.create(data=data)
print result.status_code
print result.json()
```

In the logs I can see it outputs "unauthorized". The [f-strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)#Expressions) are getting correct values. The API keys are correct as well.

I'm thinking of troubleshooting methods, but since I'm passing in correct values I'm in a corner.

I'm using the paid plan.

What can I try?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I am currently trying to integrate mailjet into a Laravel project and running into the same issue. API credentials are correct but mailjet is returning a 401 unauthorized response.